# Print Multidimensional array with incrementing key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays first one is student name and the second one is his favorite author sekection as follows

$student array is as follows

```
 array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Jane' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Michelle' (length=8)
      2 => string 'Mark' (length=4)
```

Now the second array Author $selection is as follows:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Mark Twaine' (length=11)
      1 => string 'E A Poe' (length=7)
      2 => string 'James Joyce' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Oscar' (length=11)
      1 => string 'Leo Toby' (length=7)
      2 => string 'James Joyce' (length=11)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Leo Toby' (length=11)
      1 => string 'E A Poe' (length=7)
      2 => string 'James Joyce' (length=11)
```

Now I want to display the student name and his favorite authors i.e, Jane favorite authors are Mark Twaine, E A Poe, James Joyce and Michelle favorite authors are Oscar, Leo Toby, James Joyce and Mark favorite authors are Leo Toby, E A Poe, James Joyce ...

I have tried this so far

```
foreach( $student as $key => $val  ) {
    echo $val." read ";
    foreach( $selection as $key1 ) {
        foreach ($key1 as $key2 => $val2){

        echo $val2;
        echo ' and ';
    } 
       echo "<br/>"; 
}
```

and getting this as output

```
Jane favorite is Mark Twaine and E A Poe and James Joyce and 
Oscar and Leo Toby and James Joyce and 
Leo Toby and E A Poe and James Joyce and 
Michelle favorite is Mark Twaine and E A Poe and James Joyce and 
Oscar and Leo Toby and James Joyce and 
Leo Toby and E A Poe and James Joyce and  
Mark favorite is Mark Twaine and E A Poe and James Joyce and 
Oscar and Leo Toby and James Joyce and 
Leo Toby and E A Poe and James Joyce and
```

Instead of

```
    Jane favorite is Mark Twaine and E A Poe and James Joyce
    Michelle favorite is Oscar and Leo Toby  and James Joyce
    Mark favorite is Leo Toby and E A Poe and James Joyce
```

I want foreach loop to restrict to only one single array value with incrementing key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_combine()`](https://php.net/array_combine) to combine students and selection. Then, use [`implode()`](https://php.net/implode) to echo the selection per student:

```
$student = ['Jane','Michelle','Mark'];
$selection = [
  ['Mark Twaine', 'E A Poe', 'James Joyce'],
  ['Oscar', 'Leo Toby', 'James Joyce'],
  ['Leo Toby', 'E A Poe', 'James Joyce'],
];

$comb = array_combine($student, $selection);

foreach ($comb as $student => $item) {
  echo $student . ' favorite is '. implode(' and ', $item). '<br>' ;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Jane favorite is Mark Twaine and E A Poe and James Joyce
Michelle favorite is Oscar and Leo Toby and James Joyce
Mark favorite is Leo Toby and E A Poe and James Joyce
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your second `foreach()` (`foreach( $selection as $key1 ) {`) is looping over all of the selections for every student.  At this point you need to just pick out the selection for the corresponding student (matching the key of the $student array to the one of the $selection array).

```
$student = ['Jane', 'Michelle', 'Mark'];
$selection = [['Mark Twaine','E A Poe','James Joyce'],
    ['Oscar','Leo Toby','James Joyce'],
    ['Leo Toby','E A Poe','James Joyce']];

foreach( $student as $key => $val  ) {
    echo $val." read ";
    foreach( $selection[$key] as $val2 ) {
            echo $val2;
            echo ' and ';
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

You can see the inner `foreach` uses the `$key` from the first array to pick out which selection to loop over.

You can shorten the inner loop using `implode()`, and this also gets rid of the extra 'and' in the output.

```
foreach( $student as $key => $val  ) {
    echo $val." read ".implode(' and ', $selection[$key])."<br/>";
}
```